# React & Firebase - Appending component with Firebase onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, components

Currently, I'm using a button with an onClick function to append a JSX component to the UI every time it's been pressed. I'm also using a useEffect with some firebase database logic which is an onSnapshot to get live reads on the data to display the information onto the UI.

The problem is when a user refreshes the page the onClick function that appends the JSX is deleted from the state and doesn't display the firebase data onto the UI. How would I go about sorting this problem out?

Code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DashboardBody from "./DashboardComponents/DashboardBody";
import db from "../../firebase";

function Test() {
  const [exercise, setExercise] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("users").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setExercise(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          exercise: doc.data().exercise,
        }))
      );
    });

    return;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {[...Array(count)].map((count, index) => (
        <DashboardBody key={index} exercise={exercise} />
      ))}

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `count` variable is stored in the component's state and is incremented whenever the button is clicked. When the page reloads (or the component unmounts and mounts again), the state variable is lost. To preserve the state, you would have to store it in the database (or in the browser's storage) so that you can fetch it when the component mounts again.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate it, I will look into these methods and try to apply it to my code :)